# Mutiple main files in Go project

Tags: go

I have a Go project. When I run the program `main.go` (with function `main`), it serves a web server serving a JSON object.

In the same folder I have another file `serializedata.go` (with function `main`) which writes the JSON object into a file that is served by the web server.

Now, when I try to run `go install` I get this error:

> ./serialize_data.go:17: main redeclared in this block previous
>   declaration at ./main.go:13

I want to keep both these files together as they are related. The test data needs to be serialized before it can be served.

How can I prevent to build the `serialization.go` file?

I'm from python world and there it's easy to have these utils files separately.

Comment: You can't do that. Full stop. Why would you _want_ to do that? How does it ever make sense to have two `main()` functions?

Comment: Don't use go install. Dead simple. Or use build tags. Or just stop working against the tooling.

Comment: "stop working against the tools" is the only right answer, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file in main package named `serialization.go`. but change the name of the function main with the any `exported` function with upper case letter and then call it inside the `main.go` file. Each package can have only a single main file. So if you want to create a file with `main()` function inside it declare in another package.

For eg your `main.go` should looks like.

```
package main

func main(){
    Serialize()
}
```

Inside `serialization.go` file use as

```
package main

func Serialize(){
   fmt.Println("Serialize")
}
```

Call above function inside main for serving on web browser

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question. To my understanding, by changing the `func main()` in `main.go` to call `Serialize()`, it no longer does its original purpose of running the webserver.

Comment: @robx It is an why you cannot declare two `main` functions inside a package. I have provided the reason too. This reason is related to the error you are getting of redeclared main.

Answer (score 1):

serialize_data.go should put in another folder and then `go run serialize_data.go`

Answer (score 1):

While not nessarily a good idea, if you avoid `go install` you can build several executables from the same folder just fine. One of my projects has a `tools` folder with several executables, that I build using `go build`. E.g.:

```
$ ls
Makefile cat.go find.go ls.go
$ cat Makefile
%: %.go
    go build -o $@ $<
$ make ls
go build -o ls ls.go
$ ./ls
Makefile cat.go find.go ls.go
```